# Given the triangle $ABC$...Prove that the $ME$ line always goes through a fixed point when $M$ moves.

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Given the triangle $ABC$, $M$ is the point inside that triangle. Construct $BMCD$ and $MAED$ parallelograms. Prove that the $ME$ line always goes through a fixed point when $M$ moves.

(In the drawing, I found the line $ ME $ always through the fixed point centroid $ G $ of the triangle ABC, but I have not proven it.)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec{EM}=\vec{EA}+\vec{AM}=\vec{DM}+\vec{AM}=\vec{DB}+\vec{DC}+\vec{AM}=$$
$$=\vec{CM}+\vec{BM}+\vec{AM}=\vec{CB}+\vec{BM}+\vec{BM}+\vec{AB}+\vec{BM}=3\vec{BM}+\vec{AB}+\vec{CB}.$$
In another hand, $$\vec{EG}=\vec{ED}+\vec{DI}+\vec{IG}=\vec{AM}+\frac{1}{2}(\vec{DB}+\vec{DC})+\frac{1}{3}\vec{IA}=$$
$$=\vec{AB}+\vec{BM}+\frac{1}{2}(\vec{CB}+2\vec{BM})+\frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2}\vec{CB}-\vec{AB})=$$
$$=2\vec{BM}+\frac{2}{3}\vec{AB}+\frac{2}{3}\vec{CB}=\frac{2}{3}\vec{EM}$$ and we are done!

Another way.

Let $EM\cap AI=\{G'\}$.

Thus, since $\Delta AG'E\sim\Delta IG'M,$ we obtain:
$$\frac{AG'}{G'I}=\frac{AE}{MI}=2,$$ which says that $G'\equiv G$ and we are done!

Comment: Thank you for the interesting vector solver. I'm looking for a non-vector solution, which is very difficult.

Comment: I have found another way. See now.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael Rozenberg.

Comment: You are welcome!